# Symfony3 FOSUserBundle populate table

Tags: php, symfony

I'm messing about with Symfony3 FOSUserBundle by following this Symfony [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html)

I managed to successfully install it and set it up as show in the docs. Checked by database and FSOUserBundle has created this table for me:

```
    +-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field                 | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id                    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | username              | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | username_canonical    | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
    | email                 | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | email_canonical       | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
    | enabled               | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | salt                  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | password              | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | last_login            | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | locked                | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | expired               | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | expires_at            | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | confirmation_token    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | password_requested_at | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | roles                 | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | credentials_expired   | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | credentials_expire_at | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    +-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Understand that these fields come from BasuUser which I extend in User entity.

Next step I am using Fixtures to load data into this table but what I am wondering is this wether I need to set every single field in this table i see by default the are NULL so when and how I should populate these fields?

Thx

Comment: What help do you specifically need? You haven't responded to any of my answers...

Comment: Have you read through these [Getting Started With FOSUserBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html)

Comment: Hey I would like to know which fields do i have to populate mandatory to make things work and why, which fields are automaticly populated by fos when and why. Thx and yes i did go through the docs but they dont talk about populating the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at User class from FOSUser, you see that there are setters, and constructor, that do some needed work. Look at constructor of User class:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->salt = base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 16, 36);
    $this->enabled = false;
    $this->locked = false;
    $this->expired = false;
    $this->roles = array();
    $this->credentialsExpired = false;
}
```

If you fill username by, `$user->setUsername('username')`, field `username_canonical` will be populated too. Analogically with `email` and `email_canonical`. You should set `Enabled` as true if you not require confirmation by e-mail. `Salt` is populated by constructor. Next you set `plainPassword` then `password` is automatically encoded and populated. `Last login` can be whichever. It is managed automatically when user login. `Expired` is connected only with accounts that have restricted time of being available. `Confirmation_token` is connected with e-mail confirmation of account. `Password_requested_at` allow to avoid sending hundreds e-mails with password reset. Managing roles use `add` rather than `set` because of it is array rather not field. Do not worry about empty `roles` in database for `ROLE_USER`, it is to save table volume. `credentials_expired` is default false, but you can find creative application of this column.

Finally look at my code of fixtures that create user super admin and 10 users.

```
<?php
namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
class LoadUserData extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface, ContainerAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    private $container;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        /** @var $manager \FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager */
        $manager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        /** @var $user User */
        $user = $manager->createUser();
        $user->setUsername('admin');
        $user->setEmail('admin@example.com');
        $user->setRoles(array('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'));
        $user->setEnabled(true);
        $user->setPlainPassword('admin_pass');
        $manager->updateUser($user);
        unset($user);

        $faker = \Faker\Factory::create();
        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
        {
            /** @var $user User */
            $user = $manager->createUser();
            $user->setUsername($faker->userName);
            $user->setEmail($faker->safeEmail);
            $user->setRoles(array('ROLE_USER'));
            $user->setEnabled(true);
            $user->setPlainPassword('pass');
            $manager->updateUser($user);
            $this->addReference('user.demo_'.$i, $user);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return integer
     */
    function getOrder()
    {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Super answer thank you so much for taking ur time writing it up much a appricated. This have gave me a good understanding of what's going on. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As long a you have this set in your "app/config/security.yml" file:

```
- { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Then you should be able to go to the URL `/register`, then you are prompted to register, and then you can query the `fos_user` table and you will see it get populated.

If you need to use AD Authentication, you can go through [my blog on that](https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2016/03/25/symfony-ad-integration/).